# SOLR 5 Install in a Production Environment

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud, solr5

I am a bit confused about installing SOLR 5.5.  The 5.5 manual says it is not recommended to deploy solr war on any other web/application servlet containers. It says deploy solr as a stand alone server. What does this mean? SOLR running on port 8983 is not running out of jetty? SOLR itself is a web server? How stable will it be in a prod environment?

I followed all the instructions on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production

Appreciate if someone can share their experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using Jetty, but it might not in the future (as there are quite a few things that gets easier to implement when you don't have to consider the webapp framework around your service). That's why 5.0 dropped explicit support for running in an existing container (it can still be done - but you're on your own, and features may break). At least now the environment for the application can be assumed to be a certain container and have a specific feature set.